# Which scripture mentions the method to interpret the Puranas?

Tags: puranas, dvaita, madhvacharya

Some dvaitins say that Sriman Madhvacharya gave the method to interpret the Purana like three languages, sapta bedhas.

In which scripture did Madhvacharya tell this method of interpretation of Puranas?